# Let $A$ be a 5 X 8 matrix whose rank is 3. Computer dim(Nul($A$))

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be a 5 X 8 matrix whose rank is 3. Computer dim(Nul($A$))

I believe this problem uses the formula: rank($A$) + dim(Nul($A$)) = n

So would the answer be as simple as: $$3 + x = 8$$
$$x = 8 - 3$$
$$x = 5$$

This also seems too simple to be correct... Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: It's perfectly right.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct, using the "rank-nullity" theorem. R(A) + N(A) = n

Comment: great, thanks for the confirmation.